# Create a button than send the user to the main page

Tags: android

I am new with Android Studio world. I made a two activity pages. The first button in the first page send the user to the second page which it works fine

```
public void change(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
```

but I made the same button in the second page to send the user the main page but no luck. Please see the code and let me know why I got this error.

```
 public void HomePage(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
```

This is the first activity page

```
package com.example.lenovo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Menu menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void change(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
}
}
```

and this is the second activity

```
package com.example.lenovo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.chapter2.example.lenovo.chapter2.R.layout;


public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main_activity2);
    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, 
MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void HomePage (View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: also please add some more code we are not getting anything from what you have shared

Comment: That's weird. Please post code of both the activities.

Comment: @AbuMohanad: please edit both class code in your post instead of in comment

Comment: @AbuMohanad have u declared `onClick` in xml and u have to use `Intent` for navigate between activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are switching layouts of Activity instead of changing Activity. this not right way to switch between Activities. use `startActivity` method with intent to start next Activity on Button click:

Start `MainActivity2` from `MainActivity`:

```
 public void change(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Start `MainActivity2` from `MainActivity`:

```
 public void HomePage(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and make sure to have added both Activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @AbuMohanad: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: sorry. I thought I can give everyone who gave me the right answer a check mark. I didn't aware that I can only give one person. Anyway, I put your answer a check mark. Thank you againsorry. I thought I can give everyone who gave me the right answer a check mark. I didn't aware that I can only give one person. Anyway, I put your answer a check mark. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you want use inbuilt device back button then simply put

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and if you want to go back by button click put this line

```
    bbsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity you are not launching the mainactivity2.class when you click the button, instead you are just changing the content view.

and the R.id.button2 is not registered in the first activity.

So it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to send user first page to second page using [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

You need to add `onClick` tag in that button in `activity_main` layout like this

```
android:onClick="change"
```

in `activity_main_activity2` add `onClick` tag in that button like this

```
android:onClick="HomePage"
```

In `MainActivity2` in setContentView change like this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
```

In first activity do like this

```
public void change(View v){
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

In second activity do like this

```
public void HomePage(View v){
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

> Don't forget to declare those Activities in manifest